# Using rsync to backup 4 different VPSs to a fifth VPS that uses to store backups

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync, backup, scp

Say I have 4 VPSs. In each one of these, the following cron commands run weekly, for local backups:

```
0 0 * * 6 zip -r /root/backups/dirs/html-$(date +\%F-\%T-).zip /var/www/html
1 0 * * 6 find /root/backups/dirs/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

0 0 * * 6 mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --all-databases > /root/backups/db/db-$(date +\%F-\%T-).sql
1 8 * * 6 find /root/backups/db/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

What I wish is to send a copy of each local backup (from each of the 4 VPSs), into a **fifth VPS**, that I'll use as a central backup environment. The sending should be secured as possible (in the plausible range).

How can this be done automatically (also scheduley) with rsync?

(or maybe SCP?)

Comment: "rsync" is used to mirror the files. since you're just storing the data "scp" is better.

Comment: @rajaganesh87 I'm struggling to think of a real-world situation where `scp` is significantly "better" than `rsync` running over its `ssh` transport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each backup is a single file (by archiving both files above), [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) is going to be more efficient than [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) because it does less overall work other than transferring the file.

As far as automation, you will need to set things up so that either:

1. The fifth VPS can connect to the other 4 without needing a password as a user who can read the backups (slightly easier to manage, but harder to code).
2. The four other VPS can connect to the fifth without needing a password, preferably each with a separate account (slightly harder to manage, but easier to code).

The preferred method for either is usually unencrypted SSH keys.  Once you have that, you can set up a cron job (on the fifth VPS in case 1, or each of the 4 others in case 2) that will transfer the latest backup to the desired location.

Here's a quick and dirty shell script for the second option that will copy the most recent file out of a directory to a remote system:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`ls -t "${1}" | head -n 1`
scp -pCB "${1}"/"${file}" ${2}
```

Running that with the path to the directory where the backups are stored as the first argument, and the `user@host:/path` string pointing to the location on the fifth VPS as the second argument will copy the most recent backup from the local system to the fifth VPS.

The `-p` option for SCP will preserve mtime (so you can still use the same `find` command to thin out old backups), `-C` enables compression (this may or may not improve performance, and `-B` prevents it from prompting for anything.

Comment: "_SCP is going to be more efficient than rsync because it does less overall work_". Have you any evidence for this, please? I've just tried a quick test with 50x 1MB files. Each filled with pseudo-random data. Ten samples of each 50MB run. `scp` took an average of 15.7s and `rsync` took an average of 12.0s.

Comment: Based on my own experience, if you're using network compression and the data is reasonably compressible, or dealing mostly with small files (or large numbers of files), then rsync will get better performance.  If not, then SCP tends to get better performance.  In this case, because it's a pair of backup files, they're probably big and probably reasonably incompressible, so it's likely SCP will do better in this case.

Comment: I will archive both archives into one. The single archive should be about 300MBs. Is this big by the standards you mention?

Comment: That should be big enough that SCP will do better.  One of the other things I forgot to mention though is that I almost always use rsync with the --checksum` option, which makes it significantly slower than SCP when you're just copying and not synchronizing files, so the difference isn't anywhere near as great as I was remembering.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate users for each client VPS at this stage.  Not strictly necessary but in case one VPS gets compromised you don't want it to be able to read (or write) backups from other machines.

Let's say you have accounts **vps1** **vps2**, on the backup-server VPS.

- Set each VPS to access the backup-server VPS via ssh using certificates and not passwords:

  1. Create a user (say, "backup") (not strictly necessary).
  2. Create a set of ssh-keys for user "backup" with `ssh-keygen` on each VPS.
  3. append the contents of `~/backup/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to an `~/<vps-user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` for each VPS account.  Make sure it's readable by that user only (`chmod 600 ~<vps-user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` )

From each VPS you should now be able to ssh from the "backup" account to the backup-server vps account...

- On the VPS-server machine create a directory for each client machine to write their backups, and make it rw only for that client's VPS account, for example:
  `mkdir /var/spool/big-backups/vps1; chown vps1 /var/spool/big-backups/vps1; chmod 600 /var/spool/big-backups/vps1;`
- Create a cronjob for user "backup" on each vps: `rsync -avz /root/backups/db/ -e "ssh -l vps1" /root/backups/ /var/spool/big-backups/vps1/"`.  Schedule this after the local backup jobs on the client VPS machines, obviously.  (The `z` flag on rsync is undesirable if your files are already compressed, your DB backup is not in your example...)

You can use `scp` instead of `rsync` if you prefer (I don't know why you would, but they both will work).